# How is the moon still Intact

Tags: naruto

The sage of six paths sealed the remaining part of the Juubi and formed the moon. I'm guessing he did it in a planetary Devastation kinda way. If that were the case then the Gedo Statue should have been the Core of the moon.

When Madara Stole the Gedo Statue, Shouldn't that have upset the equilibrium at the Core? (Considering just how large the gedo Statue is). I'm trying to understand this cause assuming the Juubi was sealed into forming the moon then wouldn't releasing the Juubi also mean undoing the seal, thereby causing the the moon to like, fall or something?

Comment: What makes you think that the gedo statue should have been the core of the moon? Also, the manga [contradicts itself](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:171255) about how the moon was created. Anyway this is a good question but unfortunately it was never explained, people could only guess. My good guess is that that's too much physics for naruto and not really important to the storyline for it to be explained :D

Comment: Probably it was not Earth's moon,some other planet's moon.Anyway,don't bring science into this lol,I agree with Elsbobokshy.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy from what i said earlier, If Hagoromo used Planetray Devastation to seal the Juubi. Then just like how Nagato did it, everything  within a specific radius will be attracted and traped in an overlaying lap of rocks and then formed the moon.  The Juubi would also have been trapped into it becoming the core of the moon